# Solving elliptic integrals in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions

I have an integral

$$\int_{a2}^{a1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(a1 -x)(a2 - x)(a3 - x)}}$$

And I'm trying to integrate it with

```
F[u] = (u1 - u)*(u2 - u)*(u3 - u)

L = Integrate[1/Sqrt[F[u]], {u, u1, u2}]
```

But it won't run. Any ideas why?

Comment: Does this have a closed-form formula?

Comment: Not sure. It doesn't evaluate

Comment: Yes, but that's my question. Why were you expecting an analytic answer from Mathematica? Is there a formula from a book or something? Or were you just wondering IF this has an analytic solution and wanted Mathematica to find it?

Comment: Well I know it relates to elliptic integrals and that's about it

Comment: @kcr It is an elliptic integral. So yes it has a closed form expression in terms of elliptic functions.

Comment: Plug in values for `u1, u2, u3, a1, a2` and I get a result in terms of elliptic integrals.

Comment: Maybe if you make just the right assumptions, you can get away without specifying values.

Comment: I answered many similar questions and you should examine them all carefully, e.g. [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221026/solving-equations-involving-integrals/221062#221062), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63121/integrating-a-real-function-i-get-a-complex-value-while-after-variable-transfor/160055#160055), [3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/222259/why-doesnt-integrate-evaluate-an-elliptic-integral/222271#222271) this list can be continued.

Comment: Read also  [4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158654/problem-solving-third-order-non-linear-differential-equation-in-mathematica/158663#158663), [5](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262892/convergence-of-a-complete-elliptic-integral/262893#262893), [6](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214063/the-time-like-geodesics-orbits-in-the-schwarzschild-spacetime/214076#214076), [7](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164927/optimization-of-ode-with-respect-to-the-initial-condition/164949#164949).

Comment: And it can be expressed automatically if you prescribe appropriate numbers insted of symbolic (unknown) constants, e.g.  `Integrate[1/Sqrt[(1 - u) (2 - u) (3 - u)], {u, 1, 2}]` yields `-2 I EllipticK[-1]`

Comment: @mmeent yes, I know. that was not the point.

Comment: to build a bit upon the arguments given by @Artes compare this `Integrate[1/Sqrt[(1 - u) (2 - u) (2 - u)], {u, 1, 2}]` and this `Integrate[1/Sqrt[(1 - u) (2 - u) (1 - u)], {u, 1, 2}]` against `Integrate[1/Sqrt[(1 - u) (2 - u) (3 - u)], {u, 1, 2}]` or  `Integrate[1/Sqrt[(1 - u) (2 - u) (4 - u)], {u, 1, 2}]`

Comment: final comment: thanks @Artes for providing the links. the answers are thoroughly detailed. very useful stuff. (+1) to all.

Comment: @kcr  I'm affraid the system will remove these upvotes since they were all in a minute from one user, anyway thanks.  I wrote these posts for the readers' benefits.

Comment: @Artes I'll check back again later. Good answers should be upvoted and accepted every time :-)

Comment: @kcr that's not what I asked. I asked how to evaluate that with *symbolic* limits.

Comment: I understood what you asked. However, from the excellent answers in the links provided by @Artes and from the examples I provided in the comments it should be obvious that the integral **CANNOT** be performed without any assumptions. Think of it this way: if you could do the integral for any values of $u_{1,2,3}$ without assuming anything, I would not have been able to find an example where the integral does not converge. Is that clear now?

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

F[u_] = (u1 - u)*(u2 - u)*(u3 - u);

Assuming[{u3 > u2 > u1},
 L = Integrate[1/Sqrt[F[u]], {u, u1, u2}] // Simplify]

(* (2 (-9 I EllipticK[(u1 - u3)/(u1 - u2)] + 
   EllipticK[(-u2 + u3)/(u1 - u2)]))/Sqrt[-u1 + u2] *)
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out in a comment by Akku14, there appears to be a problem with this result.

Looking at the specific case of `{u1 -> 2, u2 -> 3, u3 -> 4}`

```
L2 = L /. {u1 -> 2, u2 -> 3, u3 -> 4}

(* 2 (EllipticK[-1] - 9 I EllipticK[2]) *)
```

Using arbitrary precision to avoid machine-precision calculations,

```
N[L2, 15]

(* -20.9764604343370 - 23.5985179886291 I *)
```

Comparing with integration after substitution,

```
L3 = Integrate @@ ({1/Sqrt[F[u]], {u, u1, u2}} /. 
     {u1 -> 2, u2 -> 3, u3 -> 4})

(* -2 I EllipticK[-1] *)

N[L3, 15]

(* -2.62205755429212 I *)
```

This result agrees with direct numeric integration

```
L3 == NIntegrate[##, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 15] & @@ ({1/Sqrt[F[u]], {u, u1, u2}} /. {u1 -> 2, 
    u2 -> 3, u3 -> 4})

(* True *)
```

This indicates a problem with the general result, `L`. I will submit this to Wolfram Tech Support (`CASE:4924364`. Response: "It does appear that Integrate is returning an incorrect result in this case. I have forwarded an issue report to our developers with the information you provided").

Comment: Just a comment that I think is noteworthy: you can get an answer for other ordering than $u_3 > u_2 > u_1$ as well. At least in some cases. For instance `Integrate[1/Sqrt[(2 - u) (3 - u) (1 - u)], {u, 2, 3}]` evaluates to `2 EllipticK[-1]`. I am on `v12`.

Comment: May be a typo or a bug in 13.0.1 @BobHanlon ? NIntegrate says the result is `(2 (-I EllipticK[(u1 - u3)/(u1 - u2)] + 
     EllipticK[(-u2 + u3)/(u1 - u2)]))/
  Sqrt[-u1 + u2] /. {u1 -> 2, u2 -> 3, u3 -> 4} // N ` without the factor `9 ` at the beginning. `NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[F[u] /. {u1 -> 2, u2 -> 3, u3 -> 4}], 
 Evaluate[{u, u1, u2} /. {u1 -> 2, u2 -> 3, u3 -> 4}]] ` yield `0. - 2.62206 I `  .

Answer (score 4):

If the variables can be ordered such that $0 < \mathtt{u3} < \mathtt{u2} < \mathtt{u} < \mathtt{u1}$ , then the integral gives :

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[(u1 - u)*(u2 - u)*(u3 - u)], {u, u2, u1}, 
Assumptions -> {0 < u3 < u2 < u1}]

(* (2*EllipticK[-((u1 - u2)/(u2 - u3))])/Sqrt[u2 - u3] *)
```

If you don't like the negative argument of the elliptic integral, apply the [imaginary modulus transformation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7.5)
to get:

```
(2/Sqrt[u1 - u3])*EllipticK[(u1 - u2)/(u1 - u3)]
```

which seems correct as seen in the plot:

```
u1 = 3; u2 = 2; Plot[{NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[(u1 - u)*(u2 - u)*(u3 - u)], {u, u2, u1}], 
(2/Sqrt[u1 - u3])*EllipticK[(u1 - u2)/(u1 - u3)]}, {u3, 0, u2}, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}]
```

[image: plot]

Edit:
The case  $\mathtt{u2} < \mathtt{u1} < \mathtt{u3}$ gives

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[(u1 - u)*(u2 - u)*(u3 - u)], {u, u2, u1}, 
Assumptions -> {0 < u2 < u1 < u3}]
(* (2*(EllipticK[(u1 - u3)/(u1 - u2)] - 
 I*EllipticK[(-u2 + u3)/(u1 - u2)]))/Sqrt[u1 - u2] *)
```

a pure imaginary result and

the case $\mathtt{u2} < \mathtt{u3} < \mathtt{u1}$ contains a singularity within the integration range at $\mathtt{u3}$,that requires more attention...

```
u1 = 3; u2 = 2; Plot[{Abs[
NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[(u1 - u)*(u2 - u)*(u3 - u)], {u, u2, u1}]], 
Abs[(2*(EllipticK[(u1 - u3)/(u1 - u2)] - 
I*EllipticK[(-u2 + u3)/(u1 - u2)]))/Sqrt[u1 - u2]]},    {u3,u2, u1}],
```

because the numerical integration becomes unstable.

[image: noisy plot]

Answer (score 0):

The machinery I presented in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/213303) can be used to obtain a result in terms of the [Carlson symmetric integrals](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19#PT3). To wit,

```
With[{cc = {{a1, -1}, {a2, -1}, {a3, -1}, {1, 0}}, 
      pairs = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}, x = a2, y = a1}, 
     -2 Apply[CarlsonRF, 
             Table[With[{g1 = cc[[id]], 
                         g2 = cc[[Complement[Range[4], id]]]},
                        (Apply[Times, Sqrt[g1 . {1, x}] Sqrt[g2 . {1, y}]] + 
                         Apply[Times, Sqrt[g2 . {1, x}] Sqrt[g1 . {1, y}]])/
                        (x - y)], {id, pairs}]^2]] // Simplify
   -π CarlsonRK[a1 - a3, a2 - a3]
```

where we immediately obtain an answer in terms of the complete Carlson integral of the first kind, `CarlsonRK[]`. As a numerical example:

```
With[{a1 = 2, a2 = 3, a3 = -5},
     {N[-π CarlsonRK[a1 - a3, a2 - a3], 25], 
      NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[(a1 - x) (a2 - x) (a3 - x)], {x, a2, a1}, WorkingPrecision -> 25]}]
   {-1.148105728739062085568889, -1.148105728739062085568889}
```

This can of course be expressed in terms of the usual arithmetic-geometric mean (AGM):

```
-π CarlsonRK[a1 - a3, a2 - a3] /. CarlsonRK[x_, y_] :> 1/ArithmeticGeometricMean[Sqrt[x], Sqrt[y]]
   -(π/ArithmeticGeometricMean[Sqrt[a1 - a3], Sqrt[a2 - a3]])
```

which can then be expressed in terms of `EllipticK[]`:

```
Assuming[a1 > a3 && a2 > a3, FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[%]]]
   -((4 EllipticK[(Sqrt[a1 - a3] - Sqrt[a2 - a3])^2/
                  (Sqrt[a1 - a3] + Sqrt[a2 - a3])^2])/
     (Sqrt[a1 - a3] + Sqrt[a2 - a3]))
```