# Integrating and plotting solutions of a nonlinear dynamical system

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, special-functions

So I have an ODE

$k^2\; u'(\theta)^2 = -\frac{1}{3}u^3 + \frac{\omega}{k}u^2-2B\;u+2A$

where $B,A$ are constants.

I attempted to directly integrate in *Mathematica* with

```
G = k^2 D[u,theta]^2 = -1/3 u^3 + omega/k  u^2 - 2B u + 2A
I = Integrate[k^2 D[u,theta]^2 = -1/3 u^3 + omega/k u^2 - 2B u + 2A,u]
```

But got no luck. The official solution says that I should get

```
G = 1/3 ( (u1 - u) (u2 - u) (u3 - u) )
```

As my solution. I'm them asked to integrate $1/\sqrt{G(u)}$ as

```
Integrate[ Sqrt[G], {u, u1, u2}]
```

But again, got nowhere. How might I also plot `G`? say for `u1 = 1, u2 = 2, u3 = 1`?

Comment: You can get e.g. `Integrate[1/Sqrt[(1 - u)^2 (2 - u)], u]` yielding `-2 I ArcTan[Sqrt[-2 + u]]` if `u>2`, however in general if `u1 != u3`  i.e. (`u1` not equal to `u3` ) this will be an elliptic integral, then `u[theta]` will be an elliftic function expressible in terms of e.g. the Weierstrass elliptic function $\wp$  see e.g. this post [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63121/integrating-a-real-function-i-get-a-complex-value-while-after-variable-transfor/160055#160055). If you expect more detailed help you should ask your question more precisely.

Comment: If constants `k`, `A`, `B` and $\omega$ are symbolic you cannot prescribe `u1`, `u2`, `u3` but they can be expressed in terms of `k`, `A`, `B` and $\omega$. One can plot a general solution only if an initial condition is given.

Comment: I've explained how you can solve your equation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214063/the-time-like-geodesics-orbits-in-the-schwarzschild-spacetime/214076#214076).  I've mentioned it in comments to your [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264953/solving-elliptic-integrals-in-mathematica).

Comment: There is a difference betwen `=` and `==`.  The double `==` is for representing an equation.

Comment: @Roberto_1986  Explain meaning of symbols $ω,k,A,B$. What does this ode describe? What are interesting ranges of values of the constants? What is domain of $\theta$?

Answer (score 5):

**Special case**

There is a double root of $G$, i.e. $G(a)=0$.
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{G(u)}}=\frac{\sqrt{3} k}{\sqrt{(a-u)(a-u)(b-u)}}$$
Then the integral $\int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{G(u)}} du$ does not converge. If $\;0<a<b$ then $\int_0^z  \frac{1}{\sqrt{G(u)}} du\;$ where $0<z<a\;$ can be expressed in terms of logarithm:

```
Integrate[ (Sqrt[3] k)/Sqrt[(a - u) (b - u) (a - u)], {u, 0, z}, 
            Assumptions -> 0 < z < a < b]//TraditionalForm
```

[image]

**General case - solution in terms of special functions**

There are three different roots of $G(u)$

Since the original question haven't mentioned anything regarding a physical model, interesting ranges of parameters, domain of variables etc. we are  to guess what we could expect from a mathematical analysis. We can observe that our differential equation describes an elliptic curve in the phase space $(u(\theta),\frac{d u(\theta)}{d \theta})$.  Ususally  parameters $k$ and $\omega$ denote a spring (or elasticity) constant and an angular velocity (or frequency) respectively. The ODE may describe a nonlinear (anharmonic) oscillator and so we are rather interested in periodic solutions. A convenient tool for visualisation of the system behaviour is `Manipulate` and we can now demonstrate what happens is the phase space, here `up` stands for `u'[θ]` and `u` for `u[θ]`:

```
Manipulate[
  ContourPlot[ 
    k^2 up^2 == 2A - 2B u + ω u^2/k - u^3/3 , {u, -10, 10}, {up, -10, 10}, 
    ContourStyle -> Thick, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> TraditionalForm /@ {u[θ], u'[θ]}], 
  {{A, 1/4}, -4, 1}, {{B, 1}, -6, 2}, {{k, 2/3}, 0, 2}, {{ω, 5/4}, 1/2, 2}]
```

[image]

Here the unbounded curve is related to singular solutions while the closed curve is related to periodic solutions. Now we would like to parametrize these curves solving the ODE.

In order to solve this differential equation, let's recast it into the canonical Weierstrass form $w'(\theta)^2=4w(\theta)^3-g_2 w(\theta)-g_3\quad$ with help of a linear transformation $u(\theta)=a\; w(\theta)+b$. Solving appropriate algebraic equations we will get coefficients $a$ and $b$, while $g_2$ and $g_3$ can be easily expressed in terms of the given constants. This procedure had been applied e.g. to [solve geodesics equations in the Schwarzschild space-time](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214063/the-time-like-geodesics-orbits-in-the-schwarzschild-spacetime/214076#214076) and it was clearly expressed in [comments under earlier question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264953/solving-elliptic-integrals-in-mathematica#comment660322_264953). Dividing the original ode by $k^2 a^2$ we construct an appropriate coefficient list and solving imposed conditions we get $a$ and $b$:

```
cfl = CoefficientList[1/a^2 (2A/k^2 - 2B u[θ]/k^2 + ω u[θ]^2/k^3 - u[θ]^3/3k^2
                            ) /. u[θ] -> a w[θ] + b, w[θ]];
sol = Solve[ cfl[[4]] == 4 && cfl[[3]] == 0, {a, b}] // Flatten
```

> ```
> {{a -> -12 k^2, b -> ω/k}}
> ```

```
{g2, g3} = {-cfl[[2]], -cfl[[1]]};

dsol = DSolve[ w'[θ]^2 == 4w[θ]^3 - g2 w[θ] - g3, w[θ], t]/.sol //Simplify
```

> ```
> {{w[θ] -> WeierstrassP[ θ - C[1], {1/12 (-2B + ω^2/k^6), 
>                        -((3A k^11 - 3B k^6 ω + ω^3)/(216k^9))}]},
>  {w[θ] -> WeierstrassP[ θ + C[1], {1/12 (-2B + ω^2/k^6), 
>                        -((3A k^11 - 3B k^6 ω + ω^3)/(216 k^9))}]}}
> ```

and now we obtain the solution (the both solutions differ by the sign of the integration constant i.e. $\theta \pm c_1$ and so we write down only the first one)

```
(usol = a w[θ] + b /. sol /. dsol)[[1]] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Since the solutions are expressed by the Weierstrass elliptic function $\wp$ they involve singularities in a finite independent variable `θ` (assuming that $A, B, k,\omega\;$ are real) unless we impose certain complex parameter $c_1$.

We define half-periods:

```
{WHP1, WHP2, WHP3} = (Through @ { WeierstrassHalfPeriodW1, WeierstrassHalfPeriodW2,
                                  WeierstrassHalfPeriodW3}@{g2, g3}) /. sol;
```

and roots $e_1,e_2,e_3$ of the Weierstrass polynomial:

```
{WE1, WE2, WE3} =
  Through @ { WeierstrassE1, WeierstrassE2, WeierstrassE3}@{g2, g3} /. sol;
```

now we can factorize the Weierstrass polynomial
$$w'(\theta)^2=4w(\theta)^3-g_2 w(\theta)-g_3=4(w(\theta)-e_1)(w(\theta)-e_2)(w(\theta)-e_3)$$

```
FullSimplify[ WeierstrassP[{WHP1, WHP2, WHP3}, {g2, g3}] == {WE1, WE2, WE3} /. sol]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
FullSimplify[ 4w[θ]^3 - g2 w[θ] - g3 == 4(w[θ] - WE1)(w[θ] - WE2)(w[θ] - WE3) /. sol /.
  {A -> 1/4, B -> 1, k -> 2/3, ω -> 5/4} // N]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Let's plot an example:

```
Column[{{WHP1, WHP2, WHP3}, {WE1, WE2, WE3}} /.
       {A -> 1/4, B -> 1, k -> 2/3, ω -> 5/4} // N // Chop]
```

> ```
>  {0. - 1.57585 I, -3.62049 + 1.57585 I, 3.62049}
>  {-0.662408, 0.325374, 0.337034}
> ```

```
Plot[ReIm @ usol[[1]] //. {C[1] -> 1.575 I, A -> 1/4, B -> 1, 
                              k -> 2/3, ω -> 5/4},
     { θ, -12, 12}, Evaluated -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The solution takes the minimum and maximum values  at $\theta = m WHP3$, where $m$ is integer, and its period is $2 WHP$.

Answer (score 2):

To solve differential equation you need Mathematica functions `DSolve`(symbolical)  or `NDSolve`(numerical)

The corrected form of your ode is

```
ode = k^2 u'[theta]^2 == -1/3*u[theta]^3 + omega/k*u[theta]^2 -2 B u[theta] + 2 A
```

general solution

```
U=DSolve[ode, u, theta]
```

This solution, and your attempt separation of variables too,  need  additional knowledge about the parameters!